# Django: Querying the Database

Tags: python, django

Here's my model,

```
class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    followers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='user_follow')
```

I was wondering, how can I filter out the 3 most followed questions by the Users?

Thank You :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could order queryset by follower count. Like this:

```
from django.db.models import Count

most_followed = Question.objects.annotate(follower_count=Count('user_follow')).order_by('-follower_count')
```

To filter out 3 most followed questions:

```
top_three = most_followed[:3]
```

Comment: Thank You Sir. Lil change name "followers" was conflicting with database :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try it:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Question.objects.annotate(cnt_f=Count('followers')).order_by('user', '-cnt_f')[:3]
```

more details in the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet)

Comment: Thank You very much Sir :) Everything worked out finally!